# How is concurrency achieved in HTTP 2?

Tags: http, ssl, concurrency, tls1.2, http2

I was reading [here](https://kinsta.com/learn/what-is-http2/)

> Binary frame formats enable the exchange of multiple, concurrently open, independent bi-directional sequences without latency between successive streams.

Now my question is, how is this really achieved? How does `Binary frame formats` helps?

Comment: I think this is off-topic. But basically the relevant part is not the *binary* part but the *frame* part. Each stream consists of multiple frames and these frames can be mixed. This way you can multiplex multiple streams at the same time inside a single TCP connection.

Comment: So, is it like as each frame will have an id to identify which request is it part of HTTP/2 allows sending multiple responses/requests concurrently. But then the question arises why was this not used in HTTP/1.1? Event though 1.1 was using text instead of binary stream could they not have added some id and let multiple requests use same connection?

Comment: HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 have no concept of frames. Requests follow after each other and responses follow after each other. And adding this feature would be incompatible and thus would require a new major protocol version - which we have now with HTTP/2.

Comment: I think i understand it now. Thanks for the information